# Compose function in smlnj

Tags: sml

I have to write a function compose which accepts a list of unary functions f1,...,fn and a value v as arguments and computes f1(f2(. . . (fn(v)) . . .))... in SMLNJ

i am trying to make a curried version of it w/o using built in curry implementation, any suggestions?

how to implement it with own curry technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `::`, remove the square brackets around the pattern. Otherwise you match a 1-element list whose element is another nested list.

Also, the second case in your definition seems redundant.